# Sorting on an array of dictionary.

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to perform sorting on array of dictionary on the 'Name' field. Something is going wrong and I am not able to figure it out. This is my code.

```
myArray = [{'Name' : 'Alina'}{'Name' : 'rita'}{'Name' : 'Viva'}{'Name' : 'baby'}]

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name"  ascending:YES];
sorted_array = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

sorted_array =  [{'Name' : 'Alina'}{'Name' : 'Viva'}{'Name' : 'baby'}{'Name' : 'rita'}
```

Guide me on where am I going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Post you actual code, the code in the question will not even compile due to syntax errors.

Comment: @martin and Fogmeister how could you know both of you that i did not give any apprise to those people who gave me my question's answer.before some day i have not sufficient badge so i can not give them +1 marks.

Comment: @user3140414 you can accept an answer as correct no matter what reputation you have. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Comment: All guys :: sorry for not making checking mark true because i was new guy on stack overflow now i am understand the mean of check mark.thx every one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a case insensitive comparator:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@"Name" : @"Alina"}, @{@"Name" : @"rita"}, @{@"Name" : @"Viva"}, @{@"Name" : @"baby"}];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name"
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sorted_array = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
NSLog(@"sorted_array: %@", sorted_array);
```

NSLog output:

```
sorted_array: (
        {
        Name = Alina;
    },
        {
        Name = baby;
    },
        {
        Name = rita;
    },
        {
        Name = Viva;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you @zaph you save my lot time give you +1..and gives always badge those people who give me answer.i am not self fish buddy.